# Как перенести код из примера на реакт? React + Three.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

Подскажите, нужна анимации наподобии этой, что есть в Three.js, только с другими объектами 3D вместо кружков
https://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_particles Анимация будет на фоне некого интерфейса. Еще нужно будет добавить некую логику и импортировать другие модуль (3D). Вот еще пример https://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_cubes_tween

Пишу код на реакте. Могу ли я вставить ее в метод componentDidMount и просто вызвать как скрипт и с ней дальше работать?
Нужно ли использовать вот эту библиотеку и перенести на реакт всю логику?  https://github.com/toxicFork/react-three-renderer .

Скопировал данный код и вызвал в componentDidMount(), не может найти Stats, TWEEN. Как мне правильно его перенести на реакт?

Comment: Чисто академический интерес: если это будет использоваться фоном, то для чего нужна статистика (Stats)? И в приведенном примере с интерактивными частицами Tween.js не используется.

Comment: https://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_cubes_tween
хотел перенести еще и этот. тут используется

Comment: https://itnext.io/how-to-use-plain-three-js-in-your-react-apps-417a79d926e0 вот такая интересная статья есть.